# identify and remove single valued columns from table in R

Tags: r, apply

I have a reasonably large dataset (~250k rows and 400 cols @ .5gb) where a number of columns are single valued (ie they only have one value). To remove these columns from the dataset I use `data[, apply(data, 2, function(x) length(unique(x)) != 1)]` which works fine. I was wondering if there might be a more efficient way of doing this? This on my pc takes:

```
> system.time(apply(data, 2, function(x) length(unique(x))))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  34.37    0.71   35.15
```

Which isnt so bad for one data set, but I'd like to repeat multiple times on different datasets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lapply` instead:

```
data[, unlist(lapply(data, function(x) length(unique(x)) > 1L))]
```

Note that I added `unlist` to convert the resulting list to a vector of TRUE / FALSE values which will be used for the subsetting.

Edit: here's a little benchmark:

```
library(benchmark)

a <- runif(1e4)
b <- 99
c <- sample(LETTERS, 1e4, TRUE)
df <- data.frame(a,b,c,a,b,c,a,b,c,a,b,c,a,b,c,a,b,c,a,b,c,a,b,c,a,b,c)

microbenchmark(
  apply = {df[, apply(df, 2, function(x) length(unique(x)) != 1)]},
  lapply = {df[, unlist(lapply(df, function(x) length(unique(x)) > 1L))]},
  unit = "relative",
  times = 100)

#Unit: relative
#  expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
#apply  41.29383 40.06719 39.72256 39.16569 28.54078   100
#lapply  1.00000  1.00000  1.00000  1.00000  1.00000   100
```

Note that `apply` will first convert the data.frame to matrix and then perform the operation, which is less efficient. So in most cases where you're working with `data.frame`s you can (and should) avoid using `apply` and use e.g. `lapply` instead.

Comment: I knew that... lappy is **much** faster on data frames. @DavidArenburg, I think the `,` ensures that it is columns that are dropped?

Answer (score 1):

You may also try:

```
set.seed(40)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(letters[1:3], 3*10,replace=TRUE), ncol=10))
Filter(function(x) (length(unique(x))>1), df)
```

Or

```
df[,colSums(df[-1,]==df[-nrow(df),])!=(nrow(df)-1)] #still better than `apply`
```

Including these also in speed comparison (@beginneR's sample data)

```
 microbenchmark(
 new ={Filter(function(x) (length(unique(x))>1), df)},
 new1={df[,colSums(df[-1,]==df[-nrow(df),])!=(nrow(df)-1)]},
 apply = {df[, apply(df, 2, function(x) length(unique(x)) != 1)]},
 lapply = {df[, unlist(lapply(df, function(x) length(unique(x)) > 1L))]},
 unit = "relative", 
 times = 100)
 # Unit: relative
 #  expr        min         lq    median         uq      max neval
 #   new  1.0000000  1.0000000  1.000000  1.0000000 1.000000   100
 #  new1  4.3741503  4.5144133  4.063634  3.9591345 1.713178   100
 # apply 23.9635826 24.0895813 21.361140 20.7650416 5.757233   100
 #lapply  0.9991514  0.9979483  1.002005  0.9958308 1.002603   100
```